# MySQL - how to combine three tables to get the counts

Tags: mysql, sql, join, correlated-subquery

There are three tables, I would like to get the count of a user's total tweets and the count of likes his total tweets received.

I tried to combine two queries to get what I want but failed. Have looked through several previous questions but still can't figure it out.

- Users table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 |

- Tweets table

| id | UserId (foreign key) | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | hello |

- Likes table

| id | UserId (foreign key) | TweetId (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | hello |

First query:

```
SELECT Users.name, Users.id, COUNT(Tweets.UserId) AS UserTweetCount FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Tweets
ON Users.id = Tweets.UserId
GROUP BY Users.id
ORDER BY UserTweetCount DESC;
```

[image]

Second query:

```
SELECT Users.name, Users.id, COUNT(Likes.UserId) AS UserTweetBeLikedCount FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Likes
ON Users.id = Likes.UserId
GROUP BY Users.id;
```

[image]

I tried like below but would **get wrong `UserTweetBeLikedCount` counts**. The counts would be **UserTweetCount's**, not **UserTweetBeLikedCount's**. When I ran two queries separately, it worked well. But when I combined them together, it didn't work right.
Don't know how to display the right counts. Can someone give me hints to solve this, please?

```
SELECT Users.name, Users.id, 
COUNT(Tweets.UserId) AS UserTweetCount, COUNT(Likes.UserId) AS UserTweetBeLikedCount 
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Tweets
ON Users.id = Tweets.UserId
LEFT JOIN Likes
ON Users.id = Likes.UserId
GROUP BY Users.id
ORDER BY UserTweetCount DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try joining the Likes Table ON Users.id as opposed to Tweets.UserId ?
```..
LEFT JOIN Likes
ON Likes.UserId = Users.id
...
```

Comment: I guess your Likes table have 2 columns: the user who liked and the user who was liked. Probably you're using wrong column for joining. Pls show the table structure

Comment: @JibinJoseph Oh, it's a typo. I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: @AlecTMH I've edited the question and put the table structure on it. Thanks for your advice and yes maybe I get the wrong way from the start...(sigh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using correlated subqueries for this:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Tweets t
        WHERE u.id = t.UserId
       ) AS UserTweetCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Likes l
        WHERE u.id = l.UserId
       ) AS UserLikeCount
FROM Users u
ORDER BY UserTweetCount DESC;
```

As a note:  For performance, you want indexes on `Tweets(UserId)` and `Likes(UserId)`.

Comment: You're right!!! This is exactly what I want. Very appreciate. In fact, I'm new to SQL, so don't have too much idea about it. Had tried all day long yesterday. You really save my day.  